# How to fill color in the are between two lines in processing?

Tags: processing

I have two lines as given below:
  line (0,200, width,250);
  line (0, 250, width, 300);

How can fill the area in between them?

I tried:

```java
fill (250,250,25);
 beginShape ();
  line (0,200, width,250);
  line (0, 250, width, 300);
 endShape();
```

But it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use line() with beginShape() like that. Instead, use the vertex() function to fill your area. Something like this:

```java
beginShape();
vertex(30, 20);
vertex(85, 20);
vertex(85, 75);
vertex(30, 75);
endShape(CLOSE);
```

More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/beginShape_.html).